# why placeholder attribute does not work in summernote?

Tags: html, visual-web-developer

I am using WYSIWYG Editor Summernote. The placeholder attruibute is not working which i had provided in textarea. Why this happening ? does summernote support the placeholder ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to use the placeholder that was already defined in your textarea attributes, use:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  inheritPlaceholder: true
});
```

As per: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/3319/files

Answer (score 0):

You can define a placeholder with the placeholder option.

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  placeholder: 'write here...'
});
```

Comment: By default this is not working but when i type something and then remove those characters which i writes before then its showing placeholder can you explain me why this is behaving like this.